# Printing the Min. Gap between numbers in an array error? Where do I put the return statement?

Tags: java, arrays, return, static-methods, return-type

I need to return the minimum gap between numbers in an array. Gap as in, if a[2] = 3, and a[3] = 6, the gap would be 3.
I need to put the return statement elsewhere but I don't know where to put it because then the `smallestGap` would not be accessible. `a` stands for the array you would put in. I don't have a full class because this problem is on practice-it.

This is what I have so far:

```
 public static int minGap(int[] a){
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        int smallestGap = a[i+ 1] - a[i];
        int gap = a[i+1] - a[i];

    if(gap < smallestGap){
        smallestGap = gap;
        return smallestGap;
    }  
    }
    //if array has less than two elements return 0
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem exactly. Start from a `smallestGap` defined as larger than any other possible gap, so you can then return it. Eg:

```
int smallestGap = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; ++i) {
  int gap = a[i+1] - a[i];
  smallestGap = Math.min(gap, smallestGap);
}

return smallestGap;
```

Comment: I'm not supposed to use the Math class

Comment: I guess that you are able to implement the behavior of `Math.min` as you already did in your code.